How to export Diagram (reactFlow nodes & edges) into VSDX (Visio 2013) file format
I am trying to export my diagram like flowchart to VSDX file but, I have not found a single lead on How can I do that. also there is no such thing like structure of VSDX file or anything available.
I want to export my elements (nodes & edges) into VSDX file.
// Example nodes and edges
    const nodes = [
        { id: '1', type: 'input', position: { x: 100, y: 100 }, data: { label: 'Node 1' } },
        { id: '2', type: 'default', position: { x: 300, y: 200 }, data: { label: 'Node 2' } },
    ];

    const edges = [
        { id: 'e1-2', source: '1', target: '2', label: 'Edge from Node 1 to Node 2' },
    ];

I have tried something which is available on internet and also got help from AI but it does not really worked.
I have not a single lead on how to do it.

The Visio XML format is documented in literature, but for simple cases it works to just extract the vsdx files (these are just renamed zip files) and inspect the xml schemata of the contents.
Creating a simple VSDX file from a template is relatively straightforward: First create a very basic Visio file manually in Visio with an example set of nodes and edges that you would like to export later. Then figure out the sections in the files that Visio creates for each node and edge and finally write code that combines the static parts of the Visio template file and iterates over your data inserting templates for each node and edge.
If you are interested in a commercial solution that also converts your SVG graphics of your nodes and edges automatically to VSDX files (which unfortunately is rather non-trivial), you might want to look at the extension for "yFiles", which is a much more powerful but commercial graph visualization library.

Full disclosure: I work for the company that created yFiles and the Visio export for yFiles, and I was part of the development. I do not represent my employer, here on SO, though.

